# How to get faker working in a PHP codeception helper test

Tags: php, codeception

As shown in some example code, I have to instantiate "$faker = Factory::create();" in my methods individually for each method I want to use faker in.

I want to move this to another class, before class, or to a constructor so that I don't have to type $faker = Factory::create() in each of my methods

I have code similar to the following and have tried playing with $this, return statements, static vs non static, protected vs public methods, and nothing I seem to do seems to be working. I am new to php and am looking to see how I can make this code cleaner.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Support\Page;

use UiAutomationTester;
use \Faker\Factory;
use \Datetime;

/**
 * BaseUiHandler for wrapper methods to be inherited
 */
class BaseUiHandler
{
protected $faker;

public function Faker(UiAutomationTester $I)
{
  $faker = Factory::create();
  return $faker;
}

/**
 * get random value to use for phone number in phone input fields
 *
 * @param UiAutomationTester $I
 * @return void
 */
public static function getPhoneNumber(UiAutomationTester $I)
{
    $faker = Factory::create();
    $phone = $faker->phoneNumber;
    return $phone;
}
```

My composer.json is:

```
 {
 "require-dev": {
    "codeception/robo-paracept": "^0.4.2",
    "codeception/codeception": "^4.1",
    "codeception/module-phpbrowser": "^1.0.0",
    "codeception/module-asserts": "^1.0.0",
    "codeception/module-webdriver": "^1.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.4"
},
"require": {
    "ext-zip": "^1.15",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.2",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\Support\\": "tests/_support",
        "UiAutomationTester\\": "tests/_support/UiAutomation.php"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have not used codeception but when I write tests for phpunit, there is a `setup()` method that is run before each test, where I assign `$this->faker` to a faker instance. I'd assume codeception has something similar.

Comment: Thank you, tried that but it didn't work